# Azure DevOps release progress view is not opening

Tags: azure-devops, release

Release progress view in Azure DevOps is stuck at blank page and is not loading

Comment: Service kind of issues would probably be better to log to the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

If new release view is not loading, then it is a possibility that it might be happening because of performance issue. You can identify it is a performance issue if:

1. The browser or tab itself is not responding.
2. The release is containing lots of stages.

This is a known issue and we are working on it. For the time being to unblock yourself, you can opt-out of new release progress view feature.

To opt-out of "New release progress view", you need to opt out of "New Releases Hub" also, otherwise the option to opt-out of "New release progress view" is disabled.

To disable the preview feature:

1. Click on user icon on top right and select preview features.
2. Disable "New Releases Hub" and refresh the page.

Now repeat the same process and disable "New release progress views".

**Note:** You should opt-out of new release progress views if you are completely blocked as some of the new features are supported in new view only.